# GitHub Actions: Gradle JavaExec with dependency from build output

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, netflix-dgs, javaexec-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run the main method of a class in my project as a Gradle task. The caveat is that this class has a dependency on a class that is generated by a different task(Netflix DGS generateJava)

It is my assumption that this should be as simple as adding a `dependsOn`:

```
task printJsonSchema(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn generateJava
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run schema printer task"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = 'com.company.xyz_api.utils.JsonSchemaGenerator'
}
```

And this task works fine when I run it locally but refuses to work from within a GitHub Actions which fails during the compile step.

Github Action Logs:
(I tried to exclude all the junk but let me know if this isn't enough and I can try to get the full log attached)

```
Run ./gradlew printJsonSchema
...
> Task :xyz-api:generateJava
...
Build cache key for task ':xyz-api:generateJava' is eb70be25b6f69b5bd5dae98232698061
Task ':xyz-api:generateJava' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
...
Stored cache entry for task ':xyz-api:generateJava' with cache key eb70be25b6f69b5bd5dae98232698061
...
:xyz-api:generateJava (Thread[included builds,5,main]) completed. Took 7.043 secs.
...
:xyz-api:compileJava (Thread[included builds,5,main]) started.
...
Build cache key for task ':xyz-api:compileJava' is 677850935e99c0573c6d0134967c67e2
Task ':xyz-api:compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':xyz-api:compileJava'.
...
:xyz-api:compileJava (Thread[included builds,5,main]) completed. Took 55.844 secs.
import com.company.gen.xyzapi.types.DealInternal;
                                        ^
1 error
13 warnings
```

One of the things I've tried is trying to include the build folder in the classpath for the task but that doesn't seem to be related to compileJava failing

```
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + files("xyz-api/build/generated/sources/dgs-codegen/com/company/gen/types")
```

action:

```
name: Run Gradle Task

on: [push]

jobs:
  gradle:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: 17
      - name: Run Gradle Task
        run: ./gradlew printJsonSchema
      - name: Store Schema File as ENV VAR
        id: generate_output_file
        run: |
          schema_json=$(cat xyz-api/schema.json)
          echo "$schema_json"  >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Please include your relevant workflow in your question.

Comment: updated with action